# Looping through a string(key,value) with delimiter- Bash Scripting

Tags: bash, loops, key, delimiter

I have a value stored in a variable like

```
input="###key1,value1###key2,value2###key3,value3###"
```

I wanted to have output like

```
key1 has value1 values
key2 has value2 values
key3 has value3 values
```

Could anybody help me out how to achieve it using loops in bash scripting?

Thanks,:)

and one more doubt, what if the

```
input="###key1, value1###key2, value2###key3,value3###
```

that is with whitespace in front of values? How to trim that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way by using loop in bash.

```
lee:~/StackOverFlow $ cat test.sh 
input="$1"

input="$(echo "$input" | sed -E 's/^#+//; s/#+$//; s/#+/\\n/g;')"

echo -e "$input" | while read item; do
    k="$(echo $item | awk -F\, '{print $1}' | sed -E 's/^[[:space:]]+//')"
    v="$(echo $item | awk -F\, '{print $2}' | sed -E 's/^[[:space:]]+//')"
    echo "$k has $v values"
done
```

Output

```
lee:~/StackOverFlow $ bash test.sh "###key1,value1###key2,value2###key3,value3###"
key1 has value1 values
key2 has value2 values
key3 has value3 values
lee:~/StackOverFlow $ bash test.sh "###key1, value1###key2, value2###key3,value3###"
key1 has value1 values
key2 has value2 values
key3 has value3 values
```

1. Remove `#` the start and end of the line (`-E` Interpret regular expressions as extended)
2. Replace `#` with `\n`
3. Using while to read the whole line include whitespaces
4. Split the line into the key-value pair and remove whitespaces

Comment: 7 call to sed and 6 to awk for a single string ?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following approach (only for grep versions with `P` flag):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash                                                               

input="###key1,value1###key2,value2###key3,value3###"                            

eval $(grep -oP '[^#]*(?=###)' <<< $(echo "$input") | sed "s/,/=/")                

echo $key1                                                                      
echo $key2                                                                      
echo $key3
```

Output:

```
value1                                                                          
value2                                                                          
value3
```

For your second case the spaces around `=` must be removed, so instead of `sed "s/,/=/"` you need `sed "s/,/=/;s/  *//"`

Comment: thank you, but seems like grep P no longer works as I am using the latest one.

Answer (score 1):

With gnu sed

```
sed 's/##*/\n/g;s/^\n\|\n$//g;s/,/ has /g;s/\n\|$/ values&/g' <<<"$input"
```

---

- s/##*/\n/g _________ replace each one or more # by \n
- s/^\n\|\n$//g _______ replace the empty first and last line by nothing
- s/,/ has /g_________ replace ',' by ' has '
- s/\n\|$/ values&/g ___replace end of each line by ' values'

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.:) It is working as expected.:)